# Qt how do I wait/know when a QMainWindow is closed?

Tags: c++, qt

How do I know when a QMainWindow is closed ? So I can update a list in another window...

It would be perfect to be able to wait until it closes.

account.h:

```
class account : public QMainWindow
{
//...
```

accounts.h

```
class accounts : public QMainWindow
{
//...
public:
   account accWin;
//...
```

accounts.cpp

```
//...
void accounts::on_myAction()
{
   accWin.show();
   //how do I wait/know here for accWin to be closed ? (accWin is modal)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could override QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent*) for your QMainWindow and do your list updating there. closeEvent will be called when your window receives a close request (i.e. while it is still visible).

Alternatively, you could hook up to your window's QObject::destroyed(QObject*) signal.

Comment: It seems that I lack some OOP knowledge... what do you mean by overriding the closeEvent ? which one ?

Comment: Thanks, it should work.. but I just figured out signals and slots, seems really simple and does the work for me.. I'm starting to hate already Qt :/